# Unsupervised finetuning of BERT for embeddings only?

Tags: nlp, similarity, bert-language-model

I would like to fine-tuning BERT for a specific domain on unlabeled data and get the output layer to check the similarity between them. How can I do it? Do I need to fine-tuning first a classifier task (or question answer, etc..) and get the embeddings? Or can I just use a pre-trained Bert model without task and fine-tuning with my own data?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to fine-tune for classification, especially if you do not have any supervised classification dataset.

You should continue training BERT the same unsupervised way it was originally trained, i.e., continue "pre-training" using the masked-language-model objective and next sentence prediction. Hugginface's implementation contains class [`BertForPretraining`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforpretraining) for this.

Comment: thanks ! So this class allows me to update weight depending of my vocabulary ?

Comment: It will get tuned towards how your training data generally look like, not only the vocabulary.

Comment: Updated link [BertForPretraining][1]


  [1]: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.30.0/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForPreTraining